# Straight in 52cards+2Joker

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I have 52card (ace to king) + 2Joker
I'm supposed to compute how much straights of 5 cards I can make, excluding the straight flushes (straights with all cards being the same color)

My reasoning is :

- straight flush

  ```
  There is 9 * 4 = 36 straight flushes
  Cardinal( (1,2,3,4,5), (2,3,4,5,6), ..., (9, 10, J, Q, K) ) = 9 (or 10 if we add royal flushes)
  4 differents colors
  --> To exclude the straight flushes I only need to substract 36 to my result
  ```
- straight :

  ```
  5 cards in 4 colors generating 9 patterns :
  5^4 * 9  straights possible
  ```

My intermediate result is :

```
(5^4 * 9) - 36
```

But it doesn't take in account the 2 jokers and I just can't find how to do so.

Comment: Playing poker with jokers wild ruins the hierarchy. For instance, assuming that a player would use wilds to form three-of-a-kind, rather than two-pair, playing with jokers wild makes three-of-a-kind _more_ common than two pair. There are other similar issues.

Comment: Are the jokers distinguishable from each other?

Comment: I have no rules for the 2 jokers, I guess they're wild and we consider them distinguishable.
@alex.jordan : I didn't talk about Poker ;) but ofc you're right

Comment: Yeah, I just meant it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt your method. First count all straight flushes that may use wild cards. Then subtract that from a count of straights.

For straight flushes:

1. the five cards are all genuine; choose the lowest rank from $\{A,2,\ldots,10\}$; choose the suit; $$\binom{10}{1}\binom{4}{1}=40$$
2. one wild is used; choose which wild; the wild could replace any of the upper four ranks, but not the lower one or why wouldn't you count it as being at the high end? this leaves out the straight flushes of the form $\{*,J,Q,K,A\}$; $$\binom{10}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}+8=328$$
3. two wilds are used; they could replace any two from the top four; there are similar upper-end considerations: $$\binom{10}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2}+16=256$$

So that makes $624$ straight flushes. Can you adapt this to count straights?